# Scala: List Performance

Tags: scala, big-o, immutability, scala-collections

Doc says

> Time: List has O(1) prepend and head/tail access. Most other
>   operations are O(n) on the number of elements in the list. This
>   includes the index-based lookup of elements, length, append and
>   reverse.

Docs "proudly" mentions that most operations are O(n). Even though it's backed up by linked list, length and append operations could easily be made constant time. Also not sure if I understand why it's not doubly-linked list, which would have made reverse operation O(1).

It's the functional mumbo jumbo, isn't it?

[EDIT] Which collection can give me O(1) for all above-mentioned operations?

Answer (score 3):

Immutability is the answer. This is a simplified version of the implementation of List

```
trait List[+A] {
   def prepend[A1 >: A](a:A1): List[A]
}
case class Cons[A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A] {
   def prepend[A1 >: A](a:A1): List[A1] = Cons(a, this)
}
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
   def prepend[A1 >: A](a:A1): List[A1] = Cons(a, Nil)
}
```

With this ADT you are able to prepend but not create a double linked list. Let's se an example

```
val list1 = Cons(1, Cons(2, Nil))
val list2 = Cons(0, list1)
val list3 = Cons(-1, list1)
```

This can not be implemented as a doublylinked list without mutating the value of list1 when you create list2 and list3

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand immutability is the reason, but it comes with the cost. What's the point if it can't maintain total number of elements in a collection?

Comment: yes, it come with a cost. List is not a collection that you should use for every problem but it's without a doubt the one with best performance when you just need to read the elements sequentially and/or prepend

Answer (score 2):

For most cases you should be using a Vector instead of a List. Here is a performance comparison for different Scala collections:

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html